# Hadoop releases and new API

Tags: api, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am getting very confused about the Hadoop releases and the new API. I had a project on Hadoop 0.20.203 and i think its time to upgrade it. I wish to use a version that has YARN, which is either 0.23 or 2.0.2. Since 2.0.2 according to the Hadoop site is like 0.23 but better, i have imported version 2.0.2. The new api is supposed to be in the org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce and not in org.apache.hadoop.mapred and i already had this package from my 0.20 version, so i didn't have to change anything. The Job class has all of its constructors as deprecated, so how i am supposed to use this class? I am also getting a lot of  deprecation warnings when i run my project, that mention the mapred package.

I edited my question to include the deprecated stuff that i have on my output

```
13/02/12 00:52:57 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
13/02/12 00:52:57 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.cache.files is deprecated. Instead,   use mapreduce.job.cache.files
13/02/12 00:52:57 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
13/02/12 00:52:57 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
13/02/12 00:52:57 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.mapoutput.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.value.class
13/02/12 00:52:57 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
13/02/12 00:52:57 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
13/02/12 00:52:57 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.reduce.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduce.class
13/02/12 00:52:57 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
13/02/12 00:52:57 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
13/02/12 00:52:57 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.max.split.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize
13/02/12 00:52:57 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
13/02/12 00:52:57 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.cache.files.timestamps is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.files.timestamps
13/02/12 00:52:57 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
13/02/12 00:52:57 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.mapoutput.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.key.class
13/02/12 00:52:57 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
```

Comment: Why don't you use the corresponding classes from the new API as suggested by the warnings?

Comment: Praveen i am not getting any errors, i am just confused about the releases and the APIs..I think i am going to use the 1.X.X series since i won't be using it in a large scale.

Amar i am not using any mapred package.I only use the mapreduce package.Dont know why i am getting these warning.

Answer (score 0):

There are two major changes that happened w.r.t mapreduce framework between 20.2xx/1.x and 0.21/0.22/0.23/2.x.

- Several configuration names got renamed to better reflect what is a server side configuration property and what is a client side configuration property.

  - Client side configs: The old names are deprecated, that is why you are seeing those warnings.
  - You mentioned 2.0.2, so I suppose you are using the new framework YARN. In this case, none of the old server side configurations take any effect.
- There are two flavors of mapreduce APIs - old APIs (org.apache.hadoop.mapred) and new APIs (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce). It's a bit of a long history but the current state (and into future) is that both the old and new APIs are supported.

  - Old API is still stable and is supported in a binary compatible manner across all versions.
  - New APIs have some compatibility issues across versions (1.x -> 2.x).

You can read more about the API compatibility in Hadoop 2 here: http://hortonworks.com/blog/running-existing-applications-on-hadoop-2-yarn/